# Rebuilding reporting database in Sitecore 8

Tags: mongodb, sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers, sitecore8

I am on `Sitecore 8.0 rev. 150812` and added a fresh install for `WFFM 8 rev. 150625`

Played around with a few WFFM forms and noticed that the data was saved in MongoDb [FormData collection], but couldn't see any data in the Form reports. Just one of the forms had 1 submission against it (in the form reports and Analytics database).

There was no error in the log files.

Came across a [known issue](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/282795) with WFFM where an error occurs, when a contact submits a WFFM form twice. Nothing in my log file related to this error, but I decided to apply the fix anyway. One of the steps to apply the fix, is to rebuild the reporting database. Followed the [SDN article](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/75/xdb_upgrade_and_conversion_guide_sc75-a4.pdf) to rebuild the reporting database. However, once the rebuild process was completed, I noticed that the secondary reporting database was empty. None of the tables eg: `Contacts`, `FormFieldValues`, `Fact_FormSummary` etc had any data in them.

Again no log errors.

I don't know if it is related or not, but I had changed the sharedSessionState to `mongo` instead of the default `InProc`.

**SUMMARY**:

Two issues

1) WFFM form reports lack data.

2) Rebuilding reporting database - secondary reporting database is empty.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I would probably check with Sitecore support on this one

Comment: Are you on a single-server environment, or do you have a CM/CD? If you have a CM/CD, do you have any load-balancing?

Comment: Single Server @ZacharyKniebel. I am working on my dev machine.

Comment: Session State is likely not the cause then

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm hitting the same base issue as you - WFFM form reports aren't showing any data.

Comment: Can you check that you have done the steps that defines in this blog post: http://sitecorelabs.blogspot.com/2016/01/sitecore-80-rev-150621-rebuild.html

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the issue with rebuilding the RDB, you need to make sure that:

1. Your connection string to the secondary database is set correctly
2. That the rights to that database are granted to whatever user you are using to connect from Sitecore
3. That the processing feature is not disabled in your Sitecore setup (see [how to configure a processing server](https://doc.sitecore.net/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/xDB%20configuration/Configure%20a%20processing%20server))
4. There are no errors in the logs while the database is being rebuilt